# Build-in webcam not working

Tags: windows-7, webcam

I have a **LG** monitor with a webcam and it's not recognized by Windows in Imaging Devices. I actually don't have a category called "`Imaging Devices`". I am running Windows 7.

Comment: Get the model number of the monitor/cam and download the drivers for that model

Answer (score 0):

The webcam is most likely a USB device, so you need a USB cable between your PC and LG Monitor in addition to your standard video cable.